# How to login into SSH throue TOR

Tags: php, proxy, tor, phpseclib

I am using this class (PHPSECLIB): http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

To connect into SSH, but not find way to do it throue a proxy or TOR :)

Here is my code:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($ip, $port);
if (!$ssh->login($user, $pass)) {
    die('FAILED');
    exit;
} else {
    die('CONNECT');
    exit;
}
```

Any idea on how to add proxy for this code ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you got an answer at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/474

Comment: Yes thank you, but need tunneling for this :( want it to be automatically :)